# "realloc(): invalid next size" after multiple successful runs

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory, realloc

I keep getting this error after the array has already stored multiple lines from user input, which tells me that it's probably corrupted memory due to the line:

```
    poemArray = (char **)realloc(poemArray, count + 1);
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? A specific solution would be much appreciated!

```
    line = (char *)malloc(MaxLineLen);

    fgets(line, MaxLineLen, stdin);
    /*Get current line from user input*/
    if(count == 0)
    {
        poemArray = malloc(sizeof(char *));
        printf("1\n");
    }
    if(line[0]  == '.'){
        break;
    }
    line = (char *)realloc(line, strlen(line));

    printf("2\n");

    if(count != 0)
    {
        poemArray = (char **)realloc(poemArray, count + 1);
    }
    poemArray[count] = line;

    ++count;
```

Comment: You probably read off the end of `line` later in the code; `realloc(line, strlen(line))` cuts off the null terminator so there is no way the later code can know when to stop reading

Comment: `line = (char *)realloc(line, strlen(line));` is a meaningless line. Take the length of the string that is *already there* and *then* allocate the space for it? Uh, what?

Comment: Ah, I see, you are *reducing* the allocation for line. In that case, you forgot the `+ 1` for the terminating zero on all C strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
poemArray = (char **)realloc(poemArray, count + 1);
```

should actualy be

```
poemArray = realloc(poemArray, (count + 1) * sizeof(char *));
```

Also, this

```
line = (char *)realloc(line, strlen(line));
```

should probably be

```
line = realloc(line, strlen(line) + 1);
```

It is also unclear why you are doing the initial `malloc` for `poemArray` *before* the potential `break`. That way you might end up with `poemArray` as an uninitialized array of size 1. What is the point of having it uninitialized?

---

Additionally, note that `realloc` is designed to properly handle null pointer as its first argument. In such cases `realloc` is essentially equivalent to `malloc`. By taking advantage of this feature of `realloc` you can eliminate dedicated processing for `count == 0` state, thus ending up with much more compact and elegant code.

P.S. Why some calls to `malloc` include an explicit cast, while others don't? In any case, there's no point in casing the results of memory allocation functions in C.

Comment: `x = realloc(x, ...);` is a 99.99% bug!

Comment: @0andriy: `x = realloc(x, ...);` is definitely bad code, just like not checking the result of `malloc` for null is bad code. But first things first: the code currently contains more blatant problems that that.

Comment: Thanks guys. Code is far from finished, so i still have to add handles for null pointers.  I'm still quite novice in C also so I'm sorry if you felt like crying while reading through it, haha. Cheers